# Cut is erroring for me, saying it's not a file or directory. How can I use it to grep for "on" (See below)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Good morning! I am trying to automate something at work. So in an informix box, running the command "onstat -g dri" which gives the below output (typically):

```
root@us32999s5000d0a:/root # onstat -g dri

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC7W1XPAEE -- On-Line -- Up 39 days 22:56:20 -- 8688044 Kbytes

Data Replication at 0x56b17028:
 Type           State        Paired server        Last DR CKPT (id/pg) Supports Proxy Writes
 standard       off                                       -1 / -1         NA

DRINTERVAL   30
DRTIMEOUT    30
DRAUTO       0
DRLOSTFOUND  /usr/informix_engine/etc/dr.lostfound
DRIDXAUTO    1
ENCRYPT_HDR  0
Backlog      0
```

My question is, how can I grep ONLY for on or off, under "State?"
My issue is that when I use cut to try to isolate on or off, I get an error:

```
./AutoDoc.sh: line 27: } | /usr/bin/cut -c1-2": No such file or directory
```

Here is my script so you can see exactly what I'm doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG="C"

######## Written by Blake Smreker | b0s00dg | BSmreker@walmart.com ####
######## The goal of this script is to automate DR tickets ############

#Asks for DC number to be used later

printf "What is the four digit DC number?"

read DC

#Asks for 2 lowercase digit country code

printf "What is the two digit lowercase country code?"

read cc

#Defines dsinfx naming convention

infmx=$"dsinfmx.s${DC}.${cc}"

#Defines a variable to call upon the command for DR

onstat=$". /u/data/environment; onstat -g dri | grep -ie last -e type -e primary -e secondary -e ibm"

fred='/usr/bin/dzdo -u oseho /bin/ssh -qo PreferredAuthentications=publickey root@$infmx ". /u/data/environment; /usr/informix/bin/onstat -g dri | /usr/bin/grep -e on -e off | /usr/bin/grep -v informix |  /usr/bin/grep -v  data  | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}' | /usr/bin/cut -c1-2"'

if [ "$fred" == "on" ]; then
echo "DR is on, please resolve the ticket"
else


#Logs in to the informix box for the defined DC, then runs the above command

echo "Finding the status of DR on the primary and secondary Informix box:"

echo ""


echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

echo ""

/usr/bin/dzdo -u oseho /bin/ssh -qo PreferredAuthentications=publickey root@$infmx $onstat

echo ""

echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
fi
```

Comment: Your question should have some [MCVE] but does not. As a rule of thumb, trust the system utilities. You could start your shell script with `#!/bin/bash -vx` to understand more what is going on. Read about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). Read [`bash` reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/)

Comment: Read also the documentation of the utilities you are using (e.g. their `man` page). For `cut`, see [cut(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html). StackOverflow is not a *find-the-bugs-in-my-crappy-script* service

Comment: https://shellcheck.net gets this one. Your attempt to set `fred` seems to assume that quotes nest. They don't; the value you set fred to ends at the first whitespace following the second apostrophe. The rest of the line is interpreted as a command.

Comment: Or perhaps you are trying to use backticks but you typed them as apostrophes. Backticks are deprecated anyway; use `$(...)`. (And why are you using `$"...."` strings? )

Comment: For @BasileStarynkevitch thank you for your input. I did not come here to have the community "Find the bugs in my crappy script." As I see how you could interpret that as such, think of it more as a young person in a position for server infrastructure who is trying to learn and evolve the way they make their now primitive scripts. Going forward, I will use -vx flag to help watch how it's working. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you only need to have 2nd field's value of state(whose command on 27th line causing the issue to your code snippet), there could be many approaches for it, here are some which may help you.

***1st approach:*** With `awk` which looks for keyword State on a line then sets the variable and next line to it, it prints the 2nd field which is actual state of your command then and comes out of command then.

```
your_command | awk '/State/{flag=1;next} flag{print $2;exit}'
```

***2nd approach:*** With `awk` but since we know state will be always on 3rd line's 2nd field so hard coding it and getting it here.

```
your_command | awk 'FNR==3{print $2}'
```

***3rd approach:*** Trying with your approach by using `cut`, `head` and `tail`.

```
your_command | head -3 | tail -1 | cut -d" " -f9
```

***Additional note:*** If you see comment section as mentioned by @Basile Starynkevitch of this post you will see about URL mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 which will refer you to how we have to use commands in a variable to get its value. If we see carefully your code snippet on line 27th issue is coming that is because variable assignment has not been done properly I believe. Kindly try to read this link and post your responses after your efforts.

Comment: I think this doesn't answer the question completely, unless it shows how to properly put it in the variable; that is was is causing the error message. OP should probably read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @user000001, sure, thank you for nice suggestion will add this link into post too now.

Comment: down voter, could you please do let me know reason for down vote here?

Comment: Hey guys, so I went through all of these, and ended on the third one, naturally. So I have edited line 27 to option 3, and here's what it looks like:

    fred="/usr/bin/dzdo -u oseho /bin/ssh -qo PreferredAuthentications=publickey root@$infmx "'. /u/data/environment; /usr/informix/bin/onstat -g dri | head -3 | tail -1 | cut -d" " -f9'""

now that I changed that, I ran the script, and still got this error:
    ./AutoDoc1.sh: line 27: } | head -3 | tail -1 | cut -d" " -f9: command not found
I also fixed assigning the variable fred, so that's not the issue anymore @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @b0s00dg, cool if All is Well with script and issue fixed usually it is advised  to select any of the answer as correct answer to close post properly, cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.